# Can overlay work with a portion of a page that has codebehind functionality?

Tags: jquery, overlay

i have a complete DIV in which a have a gridview and a multiview with codebehind action:

```
                <cc3:CRDataSource EnableViewState="true" ID="DsOpciones" runat="server" SQLSelect="CartelElectronico,OpcionSeleccion_Todos">
                    <Parameters>
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="@FactorEvaluacionId" QueryStringField="FactorEvaluacionId"
                            Type="String" />
                    </Parameters>
                </cc3:CRDataSource>
                <cc3:CRGridView ID="gvTipoFactorSeleccion" runat="server" DataKeyNames="OpcionSeleccionID"
                    AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Titulo="Opciones de Factor de Evaluacion"
                    NoRowsMsg="No se encontraron Opciones para el factor de evaluación" CssClass="Table"
                    AllowExport="False" AllowFilter="False" AllowCollapse="True" EnableViewState="False"
                    PageSize="1000000000" DataSourceID="DsOpciones" OnRowUpdating="gvTipoFactorSeleccion_RowUpdating"
                    OnRowDeleting="gvTipoFactorSeleccion_RowDeleting">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" SortExpression="Nombre" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Puntos" HeaderText="Puntos" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="Eliminar"
                            ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Modificar" UpdateText="Actualizar" CancelText="Cancelar" />
                        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>                        
                </cc3:CRGridView>
                <br />
                <table>
                    <tr valign="baseline">
                        <td class="contratacionTablaSubrayadoTitulosLineas">
                            <label class="contratacionEtiquetas">
                                Opción&nbsp;(*) :</label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="contratacionTablaSubrayadoContenidoLineas">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbOpcion" runat="server" ToolTip="Nombre del Factor de la metodología de evaluación"
                                TabIndex="1" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbOpcion"
                                ErrorMessage="&nbsp;Debe digitar un nombre para la Opción" Display="Dynamic"
                                CssClass="inlineError" ValidationGroup="InsertarTipoFactorSeleccion" SetFocusOnError="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                      
                    <tr valign="baseline">
                        <td colspan="2" align="right">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="contratacionVinculos" ValidationGroup="InsertarTipoFactorSeleccion"
                                OnClick="lbInsertarTipoFactorSeleccion_Click">Insertar</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="lbCancelarInsertarTipoFactorSeleccion_Click"
                                CssClass="contratacionVinculos" CausesValidation="false">Cancelar</asp:LinkButton> ....
```

Thats just a portion of the div, my question is How can I show that DIV in a jquery overlay without loosing its functionallity? i'm asking because i manage to get it working but when i do a "that-div-postback" the screen loses the DIV and keeps only the background of the overlay.

a couple more information:

```
<button class="modalInput button" rel="#prompt">
                Buscar</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
                function pageLoad() {
                    var triggers = $("button.modalInput").overlay({
                        // some expose tweaks suitable for modal dialogs
                        expose: {
                            color: '#333',
                            loadSpeed: 200,
                            opacity: 0.3,
                            zIndex: 99
                        },
                        top: '25%',
                        closeOnClick: true
                    });
                }                

            </script>
```

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945289/active-a-overlay-jquery-from-a-js-funtion-instead-a-selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve this was insert an updatepanel inside the div i'm calling from the overlay, this way every postback will be catch by that updatepanel, and i keep the overlay on top 'till the user press Escape or the button cancel. 
Thank you for your concern jamie ;)

Answer (score 0):

As i'm not awesome enough yet to post a question to your original post, is it on a postback that you loose the functionality? Because you might want to control the postback using an ajax call?

Also - I've had trouble with elements still being accessible in some browsers with specifying an opacity.